# app is crashing on search

Tags: android, listview

The app crashes because it wants me to put `android.R.id.list` in the content method which is not possible because it expects a layout reference, not a list view reference.

Edit:
I needed to have a ListView instead of a ListActivity.

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
        // call detail activity for clicked entry
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        DatabaseTable db = new DatabaseTable(this);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is because You have a ListActivity....for that You need an ListView with id:list....

Comment: `it wants me to put android.R.id.list` This happens when you use `ListActivities` or `ListFragments`, instead of plain `ListViews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the documentation

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, **your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

To address your statement

> which is not possible

Why not? Just change your ListView in your `activity_result.xml` to use `@android:id/list`